# SDL.dll Missing...but It's not

Tags: opengl, visual-studio-2012, dll, sdl, monogame

I am on Visual Studio Profession 2012 Using MonoGame with the OpenGL template.  It is telling me that it cannot find my SDL.dll and that it is supposed to be in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoGame\v3.0\Assemblies\WindowsGL`.  I have checked and confirmed that SDL.dll is in the correct folder, yet I am still getting this error.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Try to put your SDL.dll into the same folder as your executable output.

Comment: What exactly is telling you that the DLL is missing? Is it your standard dependency not found MessageBox that Windows creates, or is the software itself trying to dynamically load the DLL at run-time?

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Its true for MSVC with C++ project, but with C# Projects, working dir is usally $BuildConfig/bin/ , so Debug/Bin or Release/Bin and he mentioned MonoGame, so I think that is a C# project.

Comment: Yes, it is a C# project.  @jordsti What is my executable output and where is that folder?  If it's program.cs, then it is already there.

Comment: @Evorlor : Your projects are normally locate in Documents\Microsoft Visual Studio 2012\Projects\YOUR SOLUTION NAME\YOUR PROJECT NAME\Debug\Bin   OR  end with Release\Bin ;

the end of the path depend on your active build configuration.